# SQLAlchemy declared_attr on Column with Foreign Key

Tags: python, postgresql, oop, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a setup where I am using an abstract Machine base class which has several subclasses for different type of machines. The reasoning is that I want to use different database schemas for those machines, which have some tables that are similar but some that are entirely different.

```
class Machine(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    __tablename__ = 'machines'

    id = Column('id', BigInteger, nullable=False, primary_key=True)


class MachineA(Machine):
    system = relationship('SystemA')
   
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'A'}


class MachineB(Machine):
    system = relationship('SystemB')
   
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'B'}
```

So far this is working as intended, but as soon as I start adding tables with foreign keys for the individual schemas, I am running into an issue.

Here is an example for a system table:

```
class System(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'system'
    __abstract__ = True

    id = Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    machine_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('machines.id'), nullable=False)
    ts = Column('ts', TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    value = Column('value', JSONB())

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('machine_id', ts, value),
                      Index('system_machine_id_index', machine_id),
                      Index('system_ts_index', ts))


class SystemA(System):

    __table_args__ = (*System.__table_args__,
                      {'schema': 'A'})


class SystemB(System):

    __table_args__ = (*System.__table_args__,
                      {'schema': 'B'})
```

When creating the tables, the following error is raised:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Columns with foreign keys to other columns must be declared as @declared_attr callables on declarative mixin classes.
  For dataclass field() objects, use a lambda:.
```

I tried using:

```
@declared_attr
def machine_id(cls):
    return Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('machines.id'), nullable=False)
```

which didn't work. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had to make machine_id a string:

```
__table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('machine_id', ts, value),
                      Index('system_machine_id_index', 'machine_id'),
                      Index('system_ts_index', ts))
```

and more importantly, reference the schema in the ForeignKey call:

```
@declared_attr
def machine_id(cls):
    return Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('A.machines.id'), nullable=False)
```

Specifying the schema in the __table_args__ is not enough for the mixin declaration.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

> ```
> @declarative_mixin
> class System(Base):
> ...
>     @declared_attr
>     def machine_id(cls):
>         ...
> ```